# Set Windows like default entry with efibootmgr, but showing menu

Tags: linux, centos, windows, dual-boot, uefi

I have this menu starting my laptop.
As you can see, I have multiple entries for CentOS 8.
But, I want to set like default, my `Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme01p1)` entry…

I was thinking in `efibootmgr`.

Reading this article https://www.lifewire.com/change-the-efi-boot-order-efibootmgr-4028027 and this article https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples and https://www.runscripts.com/support/guides/tools/multiboot-usb/dual-booting-repair

ESP (EFI System Partition)

Is it possible to keep the menu entries, changing to Windows with `efibootmgr`?

[image]

Here my `efibootmgr -v`:

```
[root@centos /]# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0017,0001,0012,0014,0015,0016,0018,0019,001A
Boot0000* CentOS Linux  HD(6,GPT,5291c15b-2f5c-42a0-b3e3-2c69f27b801b,0x1b7ec800,0x200000)/File(\EFI\centos\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,31ebd6ef-ec98-42c7-a57b-7855c2c9a1f3,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...7................
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(86488440-41bb-42c7-93ac-450fbf7766bf)
Boot0012* NVMe: SKHynix_HFM512GDHTNI-87A0B              PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,AC-E4-2E-00-0A-25-B5-D3)....2.LN........
Boot0013  UEFI Diagnostics  FvFile(f8397897-e203-4a62-b977-9e7e5d94d91b)
Boot0014* ATA HDD:  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f604)
Boot0015* ATA HDD:  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f605)
Boot0016* ATAPI CD: VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,aea2090adfde214e8b3a5e471856a354)
Boot0017* USB HDD:  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot0018* PCI LAN:  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot0019* USB FDD:  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot001A* USB CD:   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
[root@centos /]#
```

[image]

And the content of my `/etc/default/grub` file

```
[root@centos /]# cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto resume=UUID=42640b78-ce32-403c-8705-8c12e2d02855 rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
[root@centos /]#
```

[image]

```
[root@centos /]# grep /efi /proc/mounts
efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars efivarfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p6 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=winnt,errors=remount-ro 0 0
[root@centos /]# 
[root@centos /]# readlink /etc/grub2-efi.cfg
../boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg
[root@centos /]# 
[root@centos /]# readlink /etc/grub2.cfg
../boot/grub2/grub.cfg
[root@centos /]# 
[root@centos /]# sudo grub2-mkconfig -o "$(readlink /etc/grub2-efi.cfg)"
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
[root@centos /]# sudo grub2-mkconfig -o "$(readlink /etc/grub2.cfg)"
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
[root@centos /]#
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `efibootmgr` to also set the time it waits for confirmation.

However, what you're seeing is probably not the EFI loader itself, but the GRUB bootloader, which was loaded by your UEFI firmware, and will load the Linux kernel.

You can configure that to your heart's delight by editing `/etc/default/grub`. The file is fairly self-explanatory; I use `GRUB_TIMEOUT=2` and `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`.

Then run (make sure your EFI partition is mounted under /boot/efi, e.g. via `grep /efi /proc/mounts`):

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o "$(readlink /etc/grub2-efi.cfg)"
```

If that changes nothing, you're probably not actually booting via EFI and  need to do

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o "$(readlink /etc/grub2.cfg)"
```

instead.

Comment: Apparently with `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` it should mark Windows as the next boot. Unfortunately I have not been able to understand And I still can't choose Windows as the default entry.

Comment: Look in /boot/loader/entries/